# Java collect method incompatible with Checker framework

Tags: java, java-stream, checker-framework

I have introduced the Checker Framework v2.1.6 to a java8 project and have fixed all nullness errors but am stuck on the following error

```
Main.java:52: error: [assignment.type.incompatible] incompatible types in assignment.

List<String> collectedStrings = strings.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
                                                                    ^
  found   : @Initialized @NonNull List<@Initialized @Nullable Object>
  required: @UnknownInitialization @Nullable List<@Initialized @NonNull String>
```

The following (simplified) example code throws the error

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
strings.add("test");
List<String> collectedStrings = strings.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
collectedStrings.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Now I can work around this by making the result @Nullable

```
List<@Nullable String> collectedStrings = strings.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But this only cascades the error onto the next call which now thinks that collectedStrings is suspicious

Does anyone have a good work around for this?

Comment: I guess you need to provide explicit type parameter to the Collectors.toList() call. It seems that type inference is failing again. I'm not sure, though, since I'm not familiar with Checker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the Checker Framework assumes that `Collectors.toList()` returns a `List<@Nullable...>`.  This is a safe, conservative assumption, but in your context you want `List<@NonNull...>`.  The Checker Framework's type inference is currently too weak to infer the type you want.

The cleanest way to solve the problem is by changing `Collectors.toList()` to `Collectors.<String>toList()`.  (Writing just `String` is equivalent to `@NonNull String`.)

An alternative is to suppress the warning, writing `@SuppressWarnings("nullness")` on the assignment.

The code below shows all these possibilities.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable;

public class CollectorsToList {

  void m(List<String> strings) {
    Stream<String> s = strings.stream();

    // This works:
    List<String> collectedStrings1 = s.collect(Collectors.<String>toList());
    // This works:
    List<@Nullable String> collectedStrings2 = s.collect(Collectors.toList());
    // This works:
    @SuppressWarnings("nullness")
    List<String> collectedStrings3 = s.collect(Collectors.toList());

    // This assignment issues a warning due to incompatible types:
    List<String> collectedStrings = s.collect(Collectors.toList());

    collectedStrings.forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```